# How could I transform this SQL to JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

The sql is as list.

```sql
select * from product_spu where (spu_code,version) in (("code1", 1),("code2", 2));
```

I have product_spu entity, and a class of `SpuCodeAndVersion`.

```java
@Data
private static final class SpuCodeAndVersion {
    private String spuCode;
    private int spuVersion;
}
```

But I can not write jpa like this:

```sql
List<ProductSpuEntity> findAllBySpuCodeInAndVersionIn(List<SpuCodeAndVersion> codeAndVersions);
```

How could I transform it?

Comment: I don't think you can. You could pass two lists, but then it would also allow e.g. `"code1"` with `2`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You mean like this? List<ProductSpuEntity> findAllBySpuCodeInAndVersionIn(List<String> codes, List<Integer> versions);      But it doesn't help, too.

Comment: This can be done with JPA Criteria API

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this cannot be implemented without a custom JPA query.

I am explaining with the example you have provided.

```
select * from product_spu where (spu_code,version) in (("code1", 1),("code2", 2));
```

The same can be implemented in custom query as follows :

```
@Query("select s from ProductSpu where (s.spuCode, s.version) in (:#{#codeAndVersion.spuCode}, :#{#codeAndVersion.spuVersion}")
ProductSpuEntity findAllBySpuCodeInAndVersionIn(SpuCodeAndVersion codeAndVersion);
```

Now you can execute this query from a loop and pass the object and store the result in another list.

> Note : this belongs to spring-data-jpa 1.7.2 + and requires spring 4

> For more information refer this documentation : https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions